# What's the difference between the chisel tip and screwdriver tip for soldering irons?

Tags: soldering, tools

I've decided to take up learning soldering and I've seen people recommend the chisel tip for the kind of work I want to do. I took a look online and found that screwdriver tips look very similar to the chisel tips mentioned.

However, I see these two tips listed separately on this chart I found:
[image: Soldering tip chart]

From the chart and other pictures I found online, I can't see any difference between the screwdriver tip and the chisel tip, other than the "thinning" of the tip starting closer to the bottom on the screwdriver. It's a similar story for the wedge tips.

Does one tip transfer heat more effectively, or is the screwdriver tip better for getting into tight spots? Why would one be preferred over the other?

I've noticed that tips are often sorted by model numbers rather than types; are "chisel" and "screwdriver" just arbitrary names people assign to them rather than official tip types?

Comment: I have one tip for my soldering iron, and it's none of those.  It's a simple point.  Never needed anything else.

Comment: I must admit I never noticed a difference between both... I guess they are arbitrary names, since maybe some people don't know what a "chisel" refers to... ^^

Comment: In my experience, a screwdriver is often substituted for a chisel ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screwdriver tips have a similar appearance to a flat-head screwdriver with two flat edges. These tips are ideal for making big solder joints for wire to wire and wire to surface work for larger electrical and electronics projects. Chisel tips are similar but are flat-ground on one side and are used for electronics, general wiring and electrical projects. I know both screwdriver and chisel tips come in a variety of sizes too. Here are two images I found of each tip to give you an idea too. They are a bit more detailed than the ones you posted.

[Chisel](http://www.gotopac.com/PACE_1124_0013_P1_p/1124-0013-p1.htm)
[Screwdriver](http://www.gotopac.com/Weller_PTH6_p/pth6-cpr.htm)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The screwdriver, chisel and wedge are all very similar. The difference is in the amount of mass near the tip. The wedge has the most mass (least taper), followed by the chisel, then the screwdriver. All three tips can provide the same surface area to apply to the work, with the same width tip. The extra mass in the wedge will heat work more quickly whereas the screwdriver less so.

With a good soldering station, all three will maintain temperature, but you would probably prefer the screwdriver for SMT components. The longer taper also helps somewhat in getting the iron in tight spaces. The wedge, on the other hand, would be more useful for through-hole components with thick leads like power resistors or diodes, connectors and wires, etc.

Some manufacturers may not use the same terminology for these different tapers. Always check the dimensional drawing if you need a specific tip shape.

Bottom line, if you're just getting started, get the chisel. It's a good middle-ground, and you likely won't need the others just yet.